# Redirect url without changing root

Tags: nginx

I want change url like this

> mysite.org/myhtml5/index.html.txt 
>  mysite.org/myhtml5/opera/index.html.txt 
>   mysite.org/myhtml5/clicker/index.html.txt

To

> mysite.org/myhtml5/index.html 
>  mysite.org/myhtml5/opera/index.html 
>   mysite.org/myhtml5/clicker/index.html

so i tried like this

> location ~ $/index.html.txt {
>   return 302 $1/index.html; 
> }

But it's not working. Would you help me? T_T

and i'm a newbie so i don't know about rule or like something. let me know when i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can't you just remove the .txt extensions from your files ? Or did you just simplified the question ?

Comment: no it's for avoid embed rename system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
rewrite /(.*)$ /$1.txt last;
```

Comment: i need redirect index.html.txt to index.html

Answer (score 0):

i solved.

> location ~ /index.html.txt {
>  
>   return 302 index.html 
>  }